# Repetição de cor estilo zebra só que de 5 em 5

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como fazer este laço de repetição para ter 5 números de uma cor e 5 números de outra cor?

```
var collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var  html='';
for (var i in collection) {
  var cor = (i % 5 == 0) ? 'red' : 'blue';
   html+='<div style="color: '+cor+'">'+collection[i]+'</div>';

}
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = html;
```

No [**exemplo neste fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xkq46ecf/) ele só faz os intermediários.

Comment: Ivan da pra fazer isso com apenas **uma linha de CSS**... Se quiser posto uma resposta pra vc só para constar.

Comment: @hugocsl uma linha infelizmente creio que não, o que consegui foi no máximo com nth-child e aplicando valores negativos para aplicar estilo aos 4 elementos anteriores https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/299340/3635 - mas se souber de alguma implementação por favor não deixe de responder, pode garantir alguns pontos :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento usa valor negativo sim, mas é dessa forma, pode testar ai :) `ul li:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+10) { color:red; }` Vai pegar cor vermelha só do item 6 ao 10.

Comment: @hugocsl isso não funciona, ele só vai afetar 5 elementos, os que vierem após os 5 primeiros.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim rss, pega o range de 5 elementos. Eu tinha entendido que era isso que ele queria os 5 primeiros e os 5 últimos pega o estilo padrão que ele setar, e no 6 ao 10 o estilo do nth-child...Eu gostaria é que tivesse um Even e Odd com range, tipo `Odd-n5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está trocando a cor em toda iteração do loop, mas só precisa trocar quando for múltiplo de 5. Falta uma condição.

```js
var collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var cor = 'blue';
var  html='';
for (var i in collection) {
   if(i % 5 == 0) {
       cor = cor === 'blue' ? 'red' : 'blue';
   }
   html+='<div style="color: '+cor+'">'+collection[i]+'</div>';

}
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

O que o código faz é ficar vermelho se a posição for múltipla de `5` e azul caso contrário. Para fazer a troca de `5` em `5` pode definir uma cor inicial, e a cada posição múltipla de `5` trocar a cor em que vai.

Exemplo:

```js
var collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var  html='';
var cor = 'red'; //inicia com red
for (var i in collection) {
   if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) { //se multiplo de 5
       cor = cor == 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red'; // alterna a cor
   }
   html+='<div style="color: '+cor+'">'+collection[i]+'</div>';

}
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Até consegue aplicar mais cores se utilizar uma solução baseada num array de cores:

```js
var collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var html='';
var cores = ['red','blue','green']; //cores disponiveis
var corCorrente = 0;
for (var i in collection) {
   if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) { 
       //aumentar cor corrente e se passar o limite volta a 0
       corCorrente = (corCorrente + 1) % collection.length;
   }
   html+='<div style="color: '+cores[corCorrente]+'">'+collection[i]+'</div>';
}
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Já que incluiu a tag [css](/questions/tagged/css) então a minha sugestão é que faça proveito disto, usando o seletor `:nth-child(...)`, semelhante ao que [*Sveen*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/299320/3635) fez.

No entanto acho que precisa de uma explicação, eu fiz um exemplo de uma forma mais simples (do meu ponto de vista) de poder modificar

```js
var collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var  html = '<div>' + collection.join('</div><div>') + '</div>';

document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = html;
```

```css
#data > div:nth-child(5n),
#data > div:nth-child(5n-1),
#data > div:nth-child(5n-2),
#data > div:nth-child(5n-3),
#data > div:nth-child(5n-4) {
    color: red;
}

#data > div:nth-child(10n),
#data > div:nth-child(10n-1),
#data > div:nth-child(10n-2),
#data > div:nth-child(10n-3),
#data > div:nth-child(10n-4) {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

---

### Explicação sobre o uso de nth-child

Primeiro devo dizer que neste uso você nem irá precisar iterar, note que não é necessário `for`, o `join` já resolveu:

```
var html = '<div>' + collection.join('</div><div>') + '</div>';
```

Agora sobre o CSS, este primeiro:

```css
#data > div:nth-child(5n),
#data > div:nth-child(5n-1),
#data > div:nth-child(5n-2),
#data > div:nth-child(5n-3),
#data > div:nth-child(5n-4)
```

Note que:

- `5n` irá aplicar o efeito a cada 5 elementos
- `5n-1` irá aplicar o efeito a no elemento que for anterior (-1) ao quinto elemento de cada ciclo
- `5n-2` irá aplicar o efeito a no elemento que for anterior em 2 posições (-2) ao quinto elemento de cada ciclo
- `5n-3` irá aplicar o efeito a no elemento que for anterior em 3 posições (-3) ao quinto elemento de cada ciclo
- `5n-4` irá aplicar o efeito a no elemento que for anterior em 4 posições (-4) ao quinto elemento de cada ciclo

Desta forma irá aplicar a cada 5 elementos e a cada 4 elementos anteriores a cda um destes

Agora este:

```css
#data > div:nth-child(10n),
#data > div:nth-child(10n-1),
#data > div:nth-child(10n-2),
#data > div:nth-child(10n-3),
#data > div:nth-child(10n-4) {
    color: blue;
}
```

Este é bem semelhante, no entanto a contagem começa do 10, ou seja de 10 em 10 elementos, e então vem aplicando o estilo aos 4 elementos anteriores a cada um dos décimos elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer usando só **css** com  **nth-child**

```js
var collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var  html='';
for (var i in collection) {
    html+='<div>'+collection[i]+'</div>';
}
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = html;
```

```css
#data > div{
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
}

#data > div:nth-child(11n - 5),#data > div:nth-child(11n - 4),#data > div:nth-child(11n - 3), #data > div:nth-child(11n - 2), #data > div:nth-child(11n - 1){
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

#data > div:nth-child(11n - 11),#data > div:nth-child(11n - 10),#data > div:nth-child(11n - 9),#data > div:nth-child(11n - 8), #data > div:nth-child(11n - 7), #data > div:nth-child(11n - 6){
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551936/css3-nth-child-repeat-range-every-5-elements/35552293